# Designing a bluetooth 4 low energy device - what needs to be taken into account for future FCC and CE certifications

Tags: fcc, ce, bluetooth-low-energy

We are designing a BT4LE device based on Nordic chipset with chip antenna.

The question is how can we understand is it required to put the chipset into an RF shield or not?

I've seen some BT4LE device designs which were CE certified and contained no RF shield. At the same time I heard opinions that the shield is required for FCC certification. Is there anybody who can help and explain how the decision should be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shield is required for a modular device (All the RF modules with FCC certification have a shield). A non modular device, under FCC 15.245 or 15.247 (2.4GHz ISM regulations) does not require a shield, however, a shield will generally improve your performance (better SNR and noise immunity). Also, transceiver modules under FCC require a voltage regulator of some sort.

Modular in this context means that the transceiver can be assembled or replaced by the end user (easily soldered or connectorized module).

Comment: Hello, 

I read FCC 15.245 and 15.247 sections and can not seem find a requirement to shield a modular device. Are they specified in a different section?

Thank you,
Roman

Comment: Yes, I think it is in a different section, though I don't remember which section of part 15.